# "Keep it together" VS "Pull oneself together" in AE

Tags: idioms, expressions, idioms-in-context

Based on dictionary definitions, the following two idioms mean more or less the same thing:

- ["Keep it together:"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+it+together) **to remain calm**, composed, and self-possessed, especially despite or in the midst of some trouble or difficulty.

and

- ["Pull oneself together:"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull-yourself-together) **to calm oneself down** and begin to think or act appropriately.

The only nuance here in my mind is that you normally say "Keep it together" to someone prior to a bad situation, while you say i.e. "pull yourself together" to someone who is in a bad situation and is suffering its consequences at the time being.

I need your confirmation on my take. Let me provide you with some examples where I think they can be used interchangeably. Then please tell me if I'm right or wrong:

> **1.** I had a really hard time ................ after my wife died.

**a.** keeping it together 
**b.** pulling myself together

> **2.** Just ................ There's no point crying about it.

**a.** keep it together. 
**b.** pull yourself together.

Comment: I edited the thread @Mari-LouA.